# How can I optimize queries django rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the following serilizers

```
    class AutoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Auto
            fields = ("nombre",)


    class MarcaSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
        autos = AutoSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Marca
            fields = ("codigo", "descripcion", "autos")
```

ModelViewSet

```
    class MarcaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Marca.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MarcaSerializer

        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = self.queryset
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

[Querys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vASsk.png)

How can you optimize access to the base, that is, make fewer inquiries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a [**`.prefetch_related(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) that fetches the related `Auto` instances in one fetch:

```
class MarcaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Marca.objects.prefetch_related('autos').all()
        serializer_class = MarcaSerializer

        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = self.queryset
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

This will first fetch the `Marca` objects, and then look with a `JOIN` for all the `Auto` objects that are related, and fetch all these objects with a *single* fetch into memory as well.

So the `Auto` objects are loaded in *bulk* instead of lazily each time fetch the `Auto`s for a *specific* `Marca` object.

This kind of optization is documented in the article mentioned by @Jerin Peter George: ["*Optimizing slow Django REST Framework performance*"](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/).

This article also discusses how to specify such prefetches at the side of the *serializer*, such that in case other tasks are done, the prefetch is *not* done. So we could for example write:

```
class AutoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Auto
        fields = ("nombre",)


class MarcaSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    autos = AutoSerializer(many=True)

    @classmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        return queryset.prefetch_related('autos')

    class Meta:
        model = Marca
        fields = ("codigo", "descripcion", "autos")
```

and then write:

```
class MarcaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Marca.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarcaSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer
        queryset = serializer.setup_eager_loading(self.queryset)
        serializer = serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: One of the best article I've read about [Django Query Optimization](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/)

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: thanks. I added a link to the article in the answer.