# Django Rest Framework categories and childs in one model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, parent-child, django-queryset

I have a very simple ( with a first look) problem. Case - A product can be sold in a several places(shops), and every product can be represented in a single shop with a different categories and sub categories ( That is why category linked via ForeignKey with Assortment twice).
So here is My Assortment model, with several FKs.

```
class Assortment(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey('category.Category', null=True, blank=True, default=None,related_name='assortment_child')
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('category.Category', null=True, blank=True, default=None,related_name='assortment_parent')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
```

View, based on rest_framework.generics.ListAPIView

```
class InstitutionTreeCategories(generics.ListAPIView):
    """Resource to get shop's tree of categories."""

    serializer_class = serializers.InstitutionCategoriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        shop = self.get_shop()
        return Category.objects.filter(assortment_parent__shop=shop).distinct()
```

And finally, serializers

```
class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')


class CategoriesTreeSerializer(CategoryListSerializer):

    # childs = CategoryListSerializer(many=True, source='assortment_child__parent_category')
    childs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta(CategoryListSerializer.Meta):
        """Meta class."""

        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'childs')

    def get_childs(self, obj):
        qs = Category.objects.filter(assortment_child__parent_category=obj.id).distinct()
        return CategoryListSerializer(qs, many=True, context=self.context).data
```

And i need to show Category Tree for a one single shop with my API.
But the problem is - If I use serializer.SerializerMethodField - it works, but too many queries (for every parent category). I tried to avoid it using 'source' option  with my 'CategoryListSerializer' by I can't make it. Every time, I get - `'Category' object has no attribute assortment_child__parent_category`. In a shell model i've tried

```
In [8]: cat.assortment_parent.values('category').distinct()
Out[8]: (0.003) SELECT DISTINCT "marketplace_assortment"."category_id" FROM "marketplace_assortment" WHERE "marketplace_assortment"."parent_category_id" = 4 LIMIT 21; args=(4,)
<AssortmentQuerySet [{'category': 3}]>
```

So - category object has this attributes, of course it does, i used it a get_childs method. So question is - how i can use it with serializer.ModelSerializer and it's source option? ( Of course using select_related method with queryset, to avoid excess queries).

Answer (score 3):

by source option you should use `.` in instead of `__`:

```
childs = CategoryListSerializer(many=True, source='assortment_child.parent_category')
```

but still you will has many queries, to fix it you should use [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
def get_queryset(self):
    shop = self.get_shop()
    qs = Category.objects.filter(assortment_parent__shop=shop).all()
    return qs.prefetch_related('assortment_child').distinct()
```

more detail you can read in the [how-can-i-optimize-queries-django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950044/how-can-i-optimize-queries-django-rest-framework/50950088#50950088)

Comment: unfortunately thats does not work either, exception  -  ` 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'parent_category'.`

Comment: there is nothin to show, all other models is simple, Product is like a id, name, description and few images, same for shop. Category - id, name, image.  The only what matters - category and parent_category FKs and theirs related names of Assortment model.

Comment: @koles.web i still in research for good answer for your question. If i will not found it, i'll do bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and the best solution I have found is to do some manual processing in order to receive desired tree representation.
So firstly we fetch all `Assortment` for shop and then build the tree manually.

Let's look at the example.

```
def get_categories_tree(assortments, context):
    assortments = assortments.select_related('category', 'parent_category')
    parent_categories_dict = OrderedDict()

    for assortment in assortments:
        parent = assortment.parent_category
        # Each parent category will appear in parent_categories_dict only once
        # and it will accumulate list of child categories
        if parent not in parent_categories_dict:
            parent_data = CategoryListSerializer(instance=parent, context=context).data
            parent_categories_dict[parent] = parent_data
            parent_categories_dict[parent]['childs'] = []

        child = assortment.category
        child_data = CategoryListSerializer(instance=child, context=context).data
        parent_categories_dict[parent]['childs'].append(child_data)

    # convert to list as we don't need the keys already - they were used only for matching
    parent_categories_list = list(parent_categories_dict.values())
    return parent_categories_list


class InstitutionTreeCategories(generics.ListAPIView):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        shop = self.get_shop()
        assortments = Assortment.objects.filter(shop=shop)
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        categories_tree = get_categories_tree(assortments, context)
        return Response(categories_tree)
```

All in single DB query.

The problem here is that there is no explicit relation between `category` and `parent_category`. If you define `ManyToManyField` in `Category` using `Assortment` as `through` intermediate model, you will get an access which Django can understand, so you would just use attribute `childs` on `Category` for example. However this will still return all children (the same would happen if your `source` example works) categories, ignoring `shop`, so some clever `Prefetch` would have to be done to achieve correct results. But I believe manual "join" is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use prefetch_related along with serializer method field

serializer:

```python
class CategoriesTreeSerializer(CategoryListSerializer):

    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta(CategoryListSerializer.Meta):

        fields = (
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'image', 
            'children'
            )

    def get_children(self, obj):
        children = set()
        for assortment in obj.assortment_parent.all():
            children.add(assortment.category)
        serializer = CategoryListSerializer(list(children), many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

your get queryset method:

```python
def get_queryset(self):
    shop = self.get_shop()
    return (Category.objects.filter(assortment_parent__shop=shop)
           .prefetch_related(Prefetch('assortment_parent', queryset=Assortment.objects.all().select_related('category')
           .distinct())
```